# Laravel database migration is not creating table on different database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this migration file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateProjectsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        if (!Schema::hasTable('projects')) {
            Schema::create('projects', function ($table) {
                $table->bigIncrements('id_project')->index();
                $table->string('name');
                $table->string('website');
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('country_id');
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('currency_id');
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('timezone_id');
                $table->integer('is_selected')->default(0);
                $table->string('token');
                $table->integer('user_id');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }

        if (!Schema::connection('shibbir_DB1')->hasTable('projects')) {
            Schema::connection('shibbir_DB1')->create('projects', function ($table) {
                $table->bigIncrements('id_project')->index();
                $table->string('name');
                $table->string('website');
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('country_id');
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('currency_id');
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('timezone_id');
                $table->integer('is_selected')->default(0);
                $table->string('token');
                $table->integer('user_id');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }

        if (!Schema::connection('shibbir_DB2')->hasTable('projects')) {
            Schema::connection('shibbir_DB2')->create('projects', function ($table) {
                $table->bigIncrements('id_project')->index();
                $table->string('name');
                $table->string('website');
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('country_id');
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('currency_id');
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('timezone_id');
                $table->integer('is_selected')->default(0);
                $table->string('token');
                $table->integer('user_id');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }

        if (!Schema::connection('shibbir_DB3')->hasTable('projects')) {
            Schema::connection('shibbir_DB3')->create('projects', function ($table) {
                $table->bigIncrements('id_project')->index();
                $table->string('name');
                $table->string('website');
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('country_id');
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('currency_id');
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('timezone_id');
                $table->integer('is_selected')->default(0);
                $table->string('token');
                $table->integer('user_id');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('projects');
    }
}
```

Here, I am trying to create `projects` table in my default database as well as in the `shibbir_DB1`, `shibbir_DB2` and `shibbir_DB3` table. Now, when I run this command :

> php artisan migrate:fresh --seed

**Laravel is not creating the table in the `shibbir_DB1` database? Is there anything I am doing wrong?**

If I remove this condition :

```
if (!Schema::connection('shibbir_DB1')->hasTable('projects')) {
```

Then I got an error when I run the migration command:

```
SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'projects' already exists (SQL: create table `projects` (`id_project` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(191) not null, `website` varchar(191) not null, `country_id` bigint unsigned not null, `currency_id` bigint unsigned not null, `timezone_id` bigint unsigned not null, `is_selected` int not null default '0', `token` varchar(191) not null, `user_id` int not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' engine = InnoDB)

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:742
    738▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    739▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    740▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    741▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 742▕             throw new QueryException(
    743▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    744▕             );
    745▕         }
    746▕     }

      +8 vendor frames 
  9   database/migrations/2020_07_31_133736_create_projects_table.php:45
      Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder::create("projects", Object(Closure))
```

Comment: could you be running the same database on a different server? it seems to think that the table already exists.

Comment: @Mashtan I am using localhost - MAMP and I have 4 database: `shibbir_laravel`, `shibbir_DB1`, `shibbir_DB2`, `shibbir_DB3`

Comment: I manually deleted all the table from those 4 database but if run the artisan command then I got that error message.

Comment: what are your database connections? have you checked if it matches the databse set in your .env file?